# Deleting many to many row eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm using **Laravel 5.5** with **Mysql**. I have the next design of database (one part of all design). And I don't know how to delete one row of Connecta (Many to many relationship) and depending the number of clients that connection has, delete the connection too.

[image: Design of many to many relationship]
Cardinality:

- 1 client can have a lot of connections (Connexio) with one price (Tarifa) for each one.
- 1 connection (Connexio) can have a lot of clients with one price (Tarifa) for each one
- 1 price (Tarifa) can be assigned to a lot of connections and clients
- For each connection and client we have 1 direction (Direccio)

If we want to revoke a connection from the client we have 2 possibilities:

1. **Connection only have one client:**

   - We delete row relationship Connecta, delete connection and direction of the connection.
2. **Connection has more than one client:**

   - We only delete the row relationship of Connecta

Eloquent relation for **Connexio**:

```
public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class,'connecta')->withPivot('estat', 'id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Eloquent relation for **Client**:

```
public function connexions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Connexio::class,'connecta')->withPivot('estat', 'id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

How can I implement the two possibilities on a single Controller?

Comment: first of all belongs to Many I think is the wrong relationship for this. The right relationship will be hasManyThrough and price will be the mediator..check this documentation and you will understand..https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @DhavalChheda thanks for the correction. I didn't know that type of Eloquent relation.

Comment: if you set the foreign key then you can delete it and it's dependent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is use `belongsToMany` relation because I can get pivot columns, thing that I couldn't use with `hasManyThrough` relation.

**Connexio** model:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class,'connecta')->withPivot('tarifa_id', 'estat', 'id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And in controller I do diferent actions depending of the number of the clients that the connection has assigned:

```
public function destroy(ConnexioDestroy $request, Connexio $connexio, Client $client)
{
    try {
        if (count($connexio->clients) == 1) {
            // If connection only have one client we delete the relation,
            // the connection and the address of the connection
            $connecta = Connecta::findOrFail($connexio->clients[0]->pivot->id);
            $connecta->delete();
            $direccio = $connexio->direccio;

            $connexio->delete();
            $direccio->delete();
        } else {
            // If connection has more than 1 client delete only
            // the relation between the client and the connection
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($connexio->clients); $i++) {
                if ($client->id == $connexio->clients[$i]->pivot->client_id) {
                    $connecta = Connecta::findOrFail($connexio->clients[$i]->pivot->id);
                    $connecta->delete();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        // No relation between connection and client founded
        abort(422, 'No s\'ha trobat la relació entre la connexió i el client');
    }
}
```

And it works for me